# Redirect page after 2 minutes, even if window is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, countdown

I am trying to redirect a page after [2] minute, even if the page is not active. This is mainly for mobile users, who will likely leave the page, resulting in the countdown timer stopping.

When a mobile user lands on the page a message is displayed that the content will be ready in 2 min. Most won't wait around and close the window, only to return 2 min. later and still having to wait for the entire 2 min...

I am currently using the below code, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<script>
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location='http://example.com'
    }, 120000);
</script>
```

Thanks much!
Chris

Comment: not possible! JS only runs when in foreground.

Comment: I guess that is not possible, once the user close the window/tab/browser the `timeout` timer will no longer run.

Comment: You will likely have to store some information about who was there, and the time. Then you can read that from history/storage and determine how much time they should wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect after two Minutes. But you can redirect if the user gets it back into foreground after at least two minutes:

```
var before=(new Date()).getMinutes();
setInterval(function() {
  if((new Date()).getMinutes()-before >= 2){
    window.location='http://example.com';
  }
}, 1000);//compare each second
```

If you want it to work when the page was closed too, you ight store it in localStorage:

```
 localStorage.setItem("before",localStorage.getItem("before") || (new Date()).getMinutes());
setInterval(function() {
  if((new Date()).getMinutes()-localStorage.getItem("before") >= 2){
    window.location='http://example.com';
  }
}, 1000);//compare each second
```

Note that this wont work at full hour change so you might recode it so that its based on *getTime()* , but well thats up to you...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120; URL=http://example.com">
```

I have not done exhaustive testing here, but this seems to work with the latest Chrome, EDGE, and FireFox browsers, even if the page is not in focus.

Comment: excellent. even you can put this anywhere in body, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user Agent if it is in mobile. Then, set Timeout to trigger function after 2 minutes.then, redirect to your desired URL.

```js
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}

if(detectmob()){
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "http://example.com";
  }, 120000);
  

}
```